# Compare a text file to multiple text files

Tags: linux, diff

Is there a tool that runs on linux (preferably GUI) that can compare a text file to any number of other text files? I currently use [meld](https://meldmerge.org/) and it works great for up to 3 files. I am looking for something that can compare more files.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Diffuse

> [Diffuse](https://github.com/MightyCreak/diffuse) is a graphical tool for merging and comparing text files.
> **Diffuse is able to compare an arbitrary number of files side-by-side**
> and gives users the ability to manually adjust line matching and
> directly edit files. Diffuse can also retrieve revisions of files from
> Bazaar, CVS, Darcs, Git, Mercurial, Monotone, RCS, Subversion, and SVK
> repositories for comparison and merging.
>
> (This code is a fork based on the original project on SourceForge:
> https://sourceforge.net/projects/diffuse/)

I've checked and you can add up to 16 panes for comparing text files. The original project on SourceForge was not update since 2014-07-18.

[image: Diffuse]